# Polymer simple input switch

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have been playing around with Polymer, and was trying to make a script that would give different messages depending on the input, I have tried a lot of possibilities, but haven't been lucky enough to get it working. I think I might need to use PHP, I just hope someone can point out what am doing wrong

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Paper Elements Test</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="Container">
      <paper-input label="Your name here"></paper-input>
      <paper-button raised>Start conversation</paper-button>
      <div id="greeting"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      var message;
      var input = document.querySelector('paper-input');
      var button = document.querySelector('paper-button');
      var greeting = document.getElementById("greeting");     

      switch(input.value){
      case "Me":
      message = "Hello ";
      break;
      default:
      message = "Hey ";
      }

      //Click event
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
          greeting.textContent = message + input.value + ' ?';
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am trying to do is, if the input contains "Me" I want a different message. Whatever I try, I keep getting the default message.

Comment: Which version of Polymer are you using?

Comment: @Dogs I am using the latest version (1.0)

Comment: have you checked to see what `input.value` is equal to immediately before the `switch` statement?  (`console.log(input.value)`)

Comment: @sfletche Its undefined, and even after writing "Me" and clicking the button. It outputs "Me" & Undefined (http://prntscr.com/7pacn2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

**EDITED:**

```
<!-- my-switch.html -->
<link href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="my-switch">
  <template>
    <div id="container">
      <paper-input label="Your name here" value="{{name::input}}"></paper-input>
      <paper-button raised on-click="buttonClick">Start conversation</paper-button>
      <div>
        <span>{{greeting}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-switch',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        },
        greeting: {
          type: String
        }
      },
      buttonClick: function () {
        var message;
        switch(this.name) {
          case 'Me':
            message = 'Hello ';
            break;

          default:
            message = 'Hey ';
            break;
        }

        this.greeting = message + this.name;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="my-switch.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-switch></my-switch>
  </body>
</html>
```

We use [two way data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html) to capture the input value. We [attach a listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html) to the button to capture clicks. When a click occurs, we update the greeting property based on the name property, and this causes the greeting span to be updated with the proper text content.

Comment: No, it does what my code is already doing. I think one of us is misunderstanding the other. I want the greeting "Hello" to be different depending on the name. A simple switch, my code already perfectly outputs "Hello xname" I will give you an example! Whenever the textbox (Input) contains "Me" I want to get a different message than when it would contain a different name. Shouldn't that be easily achievable using an if statement / switch

Comment: It works now, but its time for me to figure out how you got it to work. I'm quite new to programming and such, wouldn't mind an explanation :)

Comment: The key is `<input value={{name::input}}`. This special syntax is called [two-way data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#two-way-native) and is used by both Polymer and Angular to tie properties (like `name`) to DOM elements (like `<input>`). After using that syntax, `this.name` and the `<input>` always have the same value, so in `buttonClick` we can check for `this.name` (instead of the input value) to do the switch.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Should I read more about two-way data binding and use it more often ? Also, do you think I could get my code to work without completely restructuring it ? Or is this really the best way to do it?

Comment: I would definitely read up a bit on two-way data binding because it is used pretty heavily in Polymer components, and then you can decide for yourself whether it is worth using for your component.